# Varriational autoencoder latent space and editing the images

Tags: neural-networks

In VAE we encode the image and take its statistics (mean and variance) I hae two questions about them:
1) How these two vectors are defining acording to what? How the dimensions of these vectors be formed?
2) if we want to edit a image with using VAE for example changing the color of skin or adding make up, how do we know the exact place of these fetures' places in the latent place?

Answer (score 1):

> In VAE we encode the image and take its statistics (mean and variance)

I wouldn't take the word "encode" too seriously here. The encoder parameterizes an *approximate* posterior $p(z|x)$.

> 1) How these two vectors are defining acording to what? How the
>   dimensions of these vectors be formed?

The encoder network outputs the mean and variance of the approximate posterior (which is typically gaussian with diagonal covariance). The dimensionality of the latent space is a hyperparameter.

> 2) if we want to edit a image with using VAE for example changing the
>   color of skin or adding make up, how do we know the exact place of
>   these fetures' places in the latent place?

By trial and error.

Comment: Thanksa lot shımao and sorry for my grammar mistakes. I didn't notice when I sent